# How to make SQL process rows as a group rather than one by one with an IF condition before?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, triggers, rowcount

I have the following code in a trigger which works designed. I would like to take this trigger rule further by only setting the CommissionAmount to 0.00 IF the invoice has 1 invoice detail row and changing the @IfMenu to a different letter.

IF the invoice detail like has more than 1 row, the CommissionAmount should be set to 0.00 and the @IfMenu can remain as 'C'.

When the records are are processed the IfMenu will be 'C'. This should change to 'M' for invoices that only have 1 InvoiceID in the InvoiceDetails table. When an InvoiceID has 2 or more InvoiceID's in the InvoiceDetails table the IfMenu can remain as C.

The issue I am having is when SQL processes rows in the InvoiceDetails table and InvoiceID '123' has 3 rows the first 2 rows will change to IfMenu 'M' and then revert back to 'C' when the 3rd row is processed due to the last row not meeting the criteria of the IF statement.

I would like to know how I can group the rows in the InvoicesDetails table so that if InvoiceID = '123' and there are are more than 2 the IfMenu should remain as 'C'

I have tried using a cursor, although I cannot use a cursor in this database due to performance.

Also tried using @@ROWCOUNT and had no luck!

```
   if (@SubmitTo = 2) and @ProductCode in ('3', '14') and @IfMenu in ('C','D') and @Branch = '9' and @CAmount <> 0.00 and @VendorNumber not in ( 'DEFAULT', '') and @VendorNumber is not null
   begin 
          update top (1) IfInvoiceDetails
          set    CommissionAmount = 0.00
          where InvoiceDetailID = @InvoiceDetailID         

          insert into tblInterfaceOverrides (InvoiceID,InvoiceDetailID,ActionTaken,OriCAmount, JobNumber) 
          values (@InvoiceID,@InvoiceDetailID,'Set Commission Amount to 0.00',@CAmount, 7) 
   end



            update top (1) IfInvoices 
            set IfMenu = 'M', Record = (select COALESCE(max(Record),0)+1 from IfInvoices where IfMenu = 'M')
            where IfInvoices.InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
```

Comment: `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Where should the TOP be?